# Math.max and Math.min NaN on undefined entry

Tags: javascript, jquery

When passing values to the `Math.max` or `Math.min` function in JavaScript, they return the highest and lowest values from the input respectively.

However, if a piece of data that is undefined is entered, e.g.

```
Math.max(5,10,undefined);
```

The result returned is `NaN`. Is there a simply way to fix this using JS/jQuery?

Comment: You can write your own wrapper function for checking, or simply implement it yourself.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

I assume the `undefined` is actually some variable.

You can substitute `-Infinity` for any `NaN` value to ensure a number.

```
var foo;

Math.max(5, 10, isNaN(foo) ? -Infinity : foo); // returns 10
```

Same concept can be used on `Math.min`, but with `Infinity`:

```
var foo;

Math.min(5, 10, isNaN(foo) ? Infinity : foo); // returns 5
```

Comment: Nice answer! Wouldn't hurt to include the Math.min implementation as well.

Comment: Instead of `isNaN(foo)` you can use `foo == foo` which is faster ([source](http://jsperf.com/nan-check)).

Comment: I use the shorter form Math.max(5, 10, foo || -Infinity)

Comment: @doug reeder that doesn’t work when foo is falsy like 0

Comment: Yes, when 0 might be the largest value, you must use the longer form.

Answer (score 11):

Write your own `max` function:

```
function max() {
    var par = []
    for (var i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++) {
        if (!isNaN(arguments[i])) {
            par.push(arguments[i]);
        }
    }
    return Math.max.apply(Math, par);
}
```

Or shorter using [array filtering](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter):

```
function max() {
    var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);
    return Math.max.apply(Math, args.filter(function(val) {
       return !isNaN(val);
    }));
}
```

Usage:

```
max(5, 10, undefined);   // output: 10
```

Comment: Great, but wouldn't it be better to use `isNaN`?

Comment: `arguments` is not a real array, unfortunately.

Comment: @Yoshi True. That's what I forgot about. Thanks!

Comment: You could use `Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments).filter ...`. ;)

Comment: @Yoshi Yes, but it becomes too complicated and slower :)

Comment: Is there any reason not to override the default `max` function (or add it to the prototype of Math) with this?

Answer (score 4):

It's as simple as:

```
// ES6 (returns: 10)
Math.max(...[5, 10, undefined].filter(Number.isFinite))
```

Or:

```
// ES5 (returns: 10)
Math.max.apply(null, [5, 10, undefined].filter(Number.isFinite))
```

I think it is readable, and simply conveys its purpose.

Explanation: We take advantage of the [`Number`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number) [`primitive wrapper object`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Primitive#Primitive_wrapper_objects_in_JavaScript), to filter out the undefined values, and then pass it to the [`Math.max`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/max) function, as arguments with the [spread operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) in ES6, or with the [`Function.prototype.apply()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply) method in ES5.

Comment: `Number.isInteger(0.2)` is false, thus, this approach is unreliable with any decimal number, e.g. `Math.max([0, 0.2].filter(Number.isInteger))`. Try `Number.isFinite` instead.

Comment: @Garrett, I had mentioned this at the end of my answer, but thanks to your comment, I moved it to the top, so it is now clearer. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Check that each number is defined before passing it to `max`. Use an sentinel value as a default (such as `-Infinity`). For min you would want to use `Infinity`:

```
var a = 5;
var b = 10;
var c = undefined;

var defaultForMax = function (num) {
    return typeof num === 'number' ? num : -Infinity;
};

c = defaultForMax(c); // c is now -Infinity

Math.max(a, b, c); // 10
```

http://jsfiddle.net/QTckE/

Answer (score 1):

```
// Returns largest numeric value; excludes NaN's.
function getMax(...args) {
 return Math.max(...args.filter(Number.isFinite));
}
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value. Please read the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), and [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Answer (score 0):

Even simpler in my opinion, if you don't mind using d3, you could do the following:

```
d3.max([5,10,undefined]) // 10
```

**From the d3 documentation (https://github.com/d3/d3-array#statistics):**

Returns the minimum value in the given iterable using natural order.

...

**Unlike the built-in Math.min, this method ignores undefined, null and NaN values; this is useful for ignoring missing data.** In addition, elements are compared using natural order rather than numeric order. For example, the minimum of the strings [“20”, “3”] is “20”, while the minimum of the numbers [20, 3] is 3.

Answer (score 0):

using falsy inside Math.max

```
var foo;

Math.max(5, 10, !isNaN(foo) && foo);
```

```
var foo;

Math.min(5, 10, !isNaN(foo) && foo);
```